# how to rewrite leaflet code to react leaflet

Tags: react-leaflet

need help with rewrite code of pure js leaflet to react leaflet.

I want to see this Overlay in react-leaflet Overlay

I think i can do it with refs, but didnt find "getTileUrl" function :(

```
createLayer () {
    const { map } = this.props.leaflet;

    L.TileLayer.Rosreestr = L.TileLayer.extend({
      options: {
        tileSize: 1024,
      },
      getTileUrl: function (tilePoint) {
        var map = this._map,
          crs = map.options.crs,
          tileSize = 1024,
          nwPoint = tilePoint.multiplyBy(tileSize),
          sePoint = nwPoint.add([tileSize, tileSize]);

        var nw = crs.project(map.unproject(nwPoint, tilePoint.z)),
          se = crs.project(map.unproject(sePoint, tilePoint.z)),
          bbox = [nw.x, se.y, se.x, nw.y].join(',');

        return L.Util.template(this._url, L.extend({
          s: this._getSubdomain(tilePoint),
          bbox: bbox
        }));
      }
    });

    L.tileLayer.rosreestr = function() {
      return new L.TileLayer.Rosreestr("https://pkk5.rosreestr.ru/arcgis/rest/services/Cadastre/Cadastre/MapServer/export?layers=show&dpi=96&format=PNG32&bbox=${bbox}&size=1024%2C1024&transparent=true&f=image");
}

L.control.layers(null, {REESTR: L.tileLayer.rosreestr({},{ minZoom: 2, maxZoom: 18}) },{collapsed: false}).addTo(map);}
```

Want put code in THIS:

```
<Map ref={(ref) => { this.map = ref }} center={center} zoom={currentZoom} style={styleLeaf} maxZoom="18"  >
<LayersControl position="topright" >
<BaseLayer checked name="Landscape">
<TileLayer
url="https://tile.thunderforest.com/landscape/{z}/{x}/{y}.png/>
</BaseLayer>
<BaseLayer name="OpenCycleMap">
<TileLayer
url="https://tile.thunderforest.com/cycle/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"/>
</BaseLayer>
</LayersControl>
<Overlay checked name="REESTR" >
<TileLayer
   ref={(ref) => { this.tile = ref }}
   attribution="REESTR" url="https://pkk5.rosreestr.ru/arcgis/rest/services/Cadastre/Cadastre/MapServer/export?layers=show&dpi=96&format=PNG32&bbox=${bbox}&size=1024%2C1024&transparent=true&f=image">
</TileLayer>
</Overlay>
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit what are you trying to achieve? It is difficult to get a solid answer when you ask 'how to rewrite leaflet code to react-leaflet'. What is the behavior you would like to achieve? You want to switch between the overlay you attach (reestr) and which other overlay or tile provider or whatever or only having this one? And why are you extending TileLayer? Do you want to apply a specific custom behavior?

Comment: i have several BaseLayers of some providers and i want add to any this provider layer with Reestr

Comment: http://www.kosmosnimki.ru/demo/PKK5Cadastre/
example